# Property 'password' does not exist on type '(Document<unknown, any, IUser> & IUser & { _id: ObjectId; }) | null'

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, express, mongoose

im kind of new to TypeScript and I'm getting this error on my express and MongoDB app.

This is my User.ts model.

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

interface IUser  {
    username: string;
    password: string;
    email: string;
    isAdmin: boolean;
  }

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema<IUser>(
    {
        username: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            unique: true,
            minlength: 3
        },
        email: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            unique: true,
        },
        password: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        isAdmin: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: false,
        }
    },
    {
        timestamps: true,
    }
)


export const UserModel = mongoose.model<IUser>("User", userSchema);
```

And this is my route where I'm getting the error when I try to access password.

```
router.get( "/:id", verifyToken, async (req: any, res: any) => {
    const user = await User.findById(req.params.id);
    if (!user) {
        res.status(404).json({ message: "User not found" });
    }

    const {password, ...other} = user;

    res.status(200).json(other);
}
)
```

Full Error:

```
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
routes/user.ts:28:12 - error TS2339: Property 'password' does not exist on type '(Document<unknown, any, IUser> & IUser & { _id: ObjectId; }) | null'.

28     const {password, ...other} = user;
```

I'm doing what it says in their [docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/typescript.html) so I'm kinda at a loss.

Answer (score 0):

```
const user: IUser | null = await User.findById(req.params.id);
```

I had to define variable user.

Answer (score 0):

This error was driving me insane. I was facing the same error and it turned out I was passing the wrong generic parameter to InferSchemaType.

Changing

```
type Account = InferSchemaType<typeof Schema>;
```

to

```
type Account = InferSchemaType<typeof accountSchema>;
```

Fixed it for me.

```
import { InferSchemaType, Schema, model } from 'mongoose';


const accountSchema = new Schema({
    username: {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
    password: {type: String, required: true},
})

type Account = InferSchemaType<typeof accountSchema>;

export default model<Account>("Account", accountSchema);
```